# Ctrl + Comma in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008-sp1

I love control-comma in VS2010. Unfortunately, I have to now work on a project that requires (for now ...) VS2008. And my beloved short-cut doesn't work! Nor can I find any matching command in the IDE settings for Keyboard to assign Control + Comma to.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing (popup window, type the name of the class, and double-click or press enter to open it) in VS2008?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Assist has an equivalent feature.

Comment: My question specifically mentions that I'm looking for a core Visual Studio feature. Additional plugins = additional licenses + additional costs, it might not be feasible or worth it for me to open that door.